# Uncaught OAuthException with Facebook php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I've seen oodles of similar questions on here, but either they aren't asking the same thing or the solution doesn't work for me.  My problem is that this gives me the Uncaught OAuthException in my error log:

```
require_once 'fb-php-sdk/facebook.php';

// Facebook App Info
$app_id = MYAPPID;
$app_secret = MYAPPSECRET;

// Load info into config array for Facebook object
$config = array(
    'appId' => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
    'fileupload' => false,
    'cookie' => true
);

// Initialize Facebook
$fb = new Facebook($config);

// Retrieve user ID
$my_access_token = $fb->getAccessToken();
$uid = $fb->getUser();

// Login if the UID was 0
if (!$uid) {

    // Login parameters including redirect URL
    $params = array(
        'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes',
        'redirect_uri' => 'MYURL'
    );

    // Log the user in
    $loginUrl = $fb->getLoginUrl($params);
}

echo '<p>w00t!</p>';
echo '<p>token1: ' . $my_access_token;

$user_profile = $fb->api('/me', 'GET', array('access_token' => $my_access_token));
echo '<p>Name: ' . $user_profile['name'] . '</p>';
```

This outputs "w00t!" followed by my token, but then it never prints my user name and it gives my the error in my log.  Any ideas?  I took the user profile code right off of an example from the documentation.

Comment: What's the error? Can you post the error as well.

Comment: Here's the error:
`[23-Feb-2013 11:33:03 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
  thrown in /home/user/public_html/testapp/fb-php-sdk/base_facebook.php on line 1254`

Comment: Your accesstoken is not active, are you hardcoding it somewhere? If you believe you are generating it everytime then the call that is being made to generate it, has issues in itself.

Comment: Yea sorry, I am very new at this.  Is there a different token I should be passing in?  I saw somewhere someone using $_SESSION[something, but that didn't work for me when I tried it.

Comment: No worries, Access Token is something which is being generated by facebook for you. This token proves to be something which allows you to have access to facebook objects (pages, feeds, photos etc). Here is the link to a small tutorial to start off with authentication - http://jobyj.in/api/facebook-authentication-using-php-sdk/ Once you learn authentication and token, then the next step would be to play with Graph Objects.